# AngularJS 1.0.7 ng-switch

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJS 1.0.7 web app with this code:

```
<div ng-switch="locationService.getLangKey() == 'en'">
                <a ng-switch-when="true" class="brand" href="/" ><img src="img/logo.png" style="height: 30px" /></a>
                <a ng-switch-when="false" class="brand" href="/{{locationService.getLangKey()}}" ><img src="img/logo.png" style="height: 30px" /></a>   
            </div>
```

While loading, in example when I refresh the page, before locationService.getLangKey() is evaluated, I see two log images. When everything is loaded, then is shown ok. I would like to avoid this ugly effect.

ng-show has the same effect, and I don´t have ng-if in this Angular version.

Any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like that:

(I don't know if this version can do that)

```
<div ng-init="url = (locationService.getLangKey() == 'en') ? '' : locationService.getLangKey()">
    <a class="brand" href="/{{url}}" ><img src="img/logo.png" style="height: 30px" /></a> 
</div>
```

Comment: AngularJS 1.0.7 has ng-init. I have tried your code. However, I don´t know if the expression is not supported by the version or there is a typo, but I´m getting this javascript error in the console: Error: Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 45-45 [?] in expression [url = (locationService.getLangKey() == 'en') ? '' : locationService.getLangKey()].

Comment: try to change the ng-init to `url = (locationService.getLangKey() == 'en' ? '' : locationService.getLangKey())` or `url = if (locationService.getLangKey() == 'en') { '' } else { locationService.getLangKey()}`

Comment: I think it´s not going to work. From Angular expressions doc https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression: No Control Flow Statements: You cannot use the following in an Angular expression: conditionals, loops, or exceptions.

Comment: so instead of ng-init do it on your controller. $scope.url = blablabla